# Cheapest way to move money from MultiBit to Coinbase

Tags: wallet, transaction-fees, multibit, coinbase.com

After the launch of MultiBit HD, I decided to move from **MultiBit** to **Coinbase**. What is the cheapest way to transfer all my money from one wallet to another? Can I somehow export/import my key/wallet (if yes, how) or the only way would be to send money and pay transaction fees (if yes, should I transfer them all at once or in smaller chunks)?

Comment: Aren't the transaction fees involved about ten cents?

Comment: Didn't yet check since I still hope to find the way to simply export/import my key/wallet from MultiBit to Coinbase :)

Comment: @NickODell this makes you wonder if OP has really considered the value of their time....it's really worth saving 10 cents to spend an hour migrating your coins to a web wallet so you no longer are spending .0001 BTC per transaction??? well you're still spending the .0001 BTC either way...now its just  through a web wallet /rant

Answer (score 2):

You should reconsider your wallet switch. Mind that Coinbase can fully control your funds and it could lead to a similar fiasco we have seen in the past (Mt.Gox, etc.). Check out the [web wallet section of bitcoin.org](https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet).

Export and import (if even possible) would expose your private keys or mnemonic seed and should therefore be avoided.

A better option would be to send your coins from Multibit HD to Coinbase. It would be one transaction and the required fee would be not very hight (~0.0003 BTC).

Answer (score 0):

You can export your wallet to Blockchain.info, and then send the bitcoin to Coinbase for 0 fees. This, by definition, is cheapest. Please notice however that if you have many small transactions ("dust"), your request might take a long time to confirm, if at all.